# NSURLConnection didFailWithError "unsupported URL" for alphanumeric link

Tags: iphone, ios, web, nsurlconnection

I am trying to download a JPG file using `NSURLConnection`. The file fails to load and the delegate `didFailWithError` states in the `error` object: **unsupported URL**

My URL is alphanumeric like this example:

```
http://www.mySite.com/myFolder/123456789_123456789_12-34-56_1234_abcd.jpg
```

I also tried to use `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` to encode the underscore and the minus sign but this didn't help. If I copy/paste the link from the code to my web browser it opens normally.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the case, there was no problem in the link or in the file name which was alphanumeric. The problem was in the `NSURL` I was by mistake putting **fileName** instead of the complete link name. Here is the code that shows the error:

```
NSURLRequest *downloadRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fileName] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:60.0];
```

The solution was simply to put instead of **fileName** the complete URL string with the file name.

Answer (score 4):

Why aren't you using NSURL?  This returns a perfectly valid URL, that can be passed into an NSURLConnection:

```
[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mySite.com/myFolder/123456789_123456789_12-34-56_1234_abcd.jpg"];
```

Or if you want escaping:

```
[NSURL URLWithString:[@"http://www.mySite.com/myFolder/123456789_123456789_12-34-56_1234_abcd.jpg" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Comment: I am using `NSURL` to build the link but I didn't post the code for it. Here is how I do it: `NSURLRequest *downloadRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fileName] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:60.0];`

Comment: Try escape the string, like I've posted in the second example, and see if that works.

Comment: I tried that too but nothing changed. By the way I tried the same code on a file named `pic001.jpg` and it worked normally!

Comment: Oops, I found the error, notice in the code above I wrote `URLWithString:fileName` which is a typing mistake, it should have been `URLWithString:theURLString`. Due to copy paste from other code I forgot to change it, and I only noticed it after I posted the code on your comment above. For that I consider you were part of the solution and I will raise your answer :)